# Can not install LLDB and Cmake inside Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-sdk-tools

There's no options to install Cmake in Tools > Android > SDK Manager

[image]

Alse I've tried to just copy cmake binary file to android-sdk/cmake/bin/cmake (as android studio suggested) but it has got some other Errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to set system-wide proxy then everything were fine :)

Comment: Hi just download a proxy VPN or ... then your whole system should connect to the Internet via that VPN, after just open android studio and download anything that you want